# Will Android WebView setPluginsEnabled() cause a crash on phone running Android 4.3?

Tags: android, android-webview

Google has been deprecating some of the methods and removing them in the newer API versions.

For example, `WebView.setPluginsEnabled()` ([link](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/18/changes/android.webkit.WebSettings.html#android.webkit.WebSettings.setPluginsEnabled_removed%28boolean%29)) has been removed in Android 4.3 (API 18). Will it cause a crash if I am running an app which uses this method on Android 4.3? Why?
This app has been targeting API 16 and released into play store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will it cause a crash if I am running an app which uses this method on Android 4.3?

No. The easiest way to test this is to try it! I ran a barebones application that calls this method on my 4.3 device with no problems.

> Why?

For legacy support. Applications such as yours shouldn't crash on newer devices simply because a method was removed in the latest SDK. As long as you compile against API 17 or lower, your app will run fine. If you try to compile against API 18 or higher, you will find that you are unable to compile.

You won't be able to leverage any new features in API 18+ (or compile against API 18) until you remove that method, but you can continue compiling against API 16.

Comment: So, you're saying that this method will never fail in any of the newer versions on Android?

Comment: As of 4.3, it works just fine. I can't promise it will work forever, though I would expect it work to work for a while. I would highly encourage you to perform testing on emulators with the latest version of Android to ensure your app works correctly for yourself.

Comment: I want to generalize this problem to any removed classes/methods in the newer API versions. I couldn't find any info anywhere if this'll work forever or not.

Comment: Relying on removed or deprecated methods is a bad idea in general. While it will continue working for the forseeable future, eventually you will want to start compiling for API 18 or higher to take advantage of some new feature (and the number of devices running < API 18 will start to diminish). If you can find a suitable replacement for the method now, why not use it?

Comment: I have been using WebView.setPluginsEnabled() and targetSdkVersion 17 in my app(already in playstoe). Now, I am about to release it's updated version with some new features. I have set the targetSdkVersion 19 but I have compiled it successfully with android build target 4.2.2. I have verified on various versions and the build runs fine. Is there any case or concern in releasing this build ?